# Target package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I run the android project in Intelij IDEA, the console shows the error and I can't run the project in my phone.
What should I do?

Comment: Could you please your manifest and the error? Thanks.

Comment: The manifest is ok,and i find the reason:my usb driver has something wrong

Answer (score 1):

The package needs to be added to the AndroidManisfest project, it may have updated the IDE, Gradle, etc... Sometimes it is necessary to manually place the package.

An example follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="com.example.NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT_HERE"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest add

```
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove and add the "Run configurations" again